# Order the color panel out

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, panel

We all know this will bring the color panel forwards: `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] orderFrontColorPanel:nil];`, but how to hide it again? I tried `orderOutColorPanel:`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, use brute force:

```
- (void)hideColorPanel {
    NSArray * wndws = [NSApp windows];
    for( NSWindow * w in wndws ){
        if( [w isKindOfClass:[NSColorPanel class]] ){
            [w orderOut:nil];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no method on NSApplication to close the color panel. It is intended that the user will have control over the panel once it is shown.

Answer (score 0):

As of in 2016. There is a method.
in Swift 3, you can toggle NSColorPanel like this:

```
func toggleColorPanel(_ sender: NSButton) {
  if /*NSColorPanel.sharedColorPanelExists() &&*/ NSColorPanel.shared().isVisible {
        NSColorPanel.shared().orderOut(self)
    } else {
        NSApplication.shared().orderFrontColorPanel(self)
    }
}
```